# progress bar using backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

There have been a bunch of questions on how to implement a progress bar and I believe I have been through all of them and I still don't know why my progress bar won't work.

Well, it seems to work only after the operation is done, which is of course not what I want. I want the progress bar to work as the main operation is doing its thing.

My code is pretty long and painful so I'm going to simplify it to make it as basic as possible.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  //Main UI Operation
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  {
   // Wait 100 milliseconds.
   Thread.Sleep(100);
   // Report progress.
   backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);     }
  }

private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs        e)
  {
   progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
  }
```

Like I said, I only see the progress bar start after my main UI operation.

WorkerReportsProgress is set to True.
Minimum and Maximum are 0 and 100 respectively.

I feel like this might be a lack of understanding on Threads.

Comment: Does "// Main UI Operation" mean that activity takes place there and you've left it out? If so, that's your problem. If `button1_Click()` returns immediately, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Siride, "\\Main UI Operation" is where I call a method that takes a significant amount of time to complete. Why is this a problem exactly and how can I fix it? Is my approach to this even accurate, or would you go about it a different way?

Comment: Did you make sure to wire up the events to the callbacks. Open the properties of the background worker, and click on the lightning bolt, so you can see the event callbacks. Make sure the ones you need have the appropriate method names in place.  I tested your code, but found I was missing this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the same code as you and found it worked. Did you forget to change the `WorkerReportesProress` property to `True`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is set to True

Comment: sorry for not noticing that.
I think you should split `Main UI Operation` to small steps and replace `Thread.Sleep(100);` with one step.
Or you can create a new BackgroundWorker object and put `//Main UI Operation` in it.

Comment: Because progress bar updating and button clicking both run in UI thread, progress bar events will not be run before button1_click returns.

Comment: Ahh I see, so its because they are both running in the same thread, they can't be processed at the same time? The `Main UI Operation` can't be split up...What would trigger the BackgroundWorker Object? I absolutely need the `Main UI Operation` to run at the button click.

Comment: like this:
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(); //run Main UI Operation in backgroundWorker2_DoWork and fire a notification when completed.
}`
but how can you know the ProgressPercentage if you can't split it?

Comment: I was using a for loop to simulate the time it takes to complete the operation. Can you explain why I would need the second BW? Couldn't I, in this case, call my Main UI Operation in the BW1?

Comment: If you place MainUIOperation and ReportProgress in a thread, because MainUIOperation is atomic, ReportProgress won't be called before UIOperation is done. I suggest a second Bgworker or a timer which calles ReportProgress in tick event.